# Where do I need to place mathexam.sty in El Capitan

Tags: mac

Since I upgraded my Mac Book to El Capitan, I am not able to use TeXworks.

I changed the path in TeXworks Preference Typesetting to `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

And then I get the following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mathexam.sty' not found.
```

I downloaded mathexam and created mathexam.sty. I placed it in the same directory `/Library/TeX/texbin`. But it still gives the same error.

Where do I need to place mathexam.sty or sty files in Mac?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working after reinstall. Probably the file was in the wrong directory or something.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled 2015basic and reinstalled it but it didn't work. So I installed MacTeX full version and it is working now.